# Indoor geolocation with high accuracy on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location, indoor-positioning-system

Can iOS Core Location give me coordinates for indoor location with an high accuracy?

If yes, which are the steps to reach them?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I understand what you say. However my question is only if there is the possibility to do that. I've already tried to look for it but without success. So I'm asking to you if it's possible and if anybody knows it, if he can provide me a link to read.

Comment: did you see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311347/core-location-indoor-positioning

Comment: Define "high accuracy". As a rule, GPS can give you accuracy to within a few metres. GPS doesn't work very well indoors but the methods that do e.g. analysing nearby wireless networks are unlikely to be any better.

Comment: I mean accuracy about know if there's another man at <= 200m from me. The problem is indoor locating.

Comment: Whats the intended functionality? I've had a similar problem before but got around it by using iBeacons and leveraging the users proximity to beacons instead of actual indoor positioning.

Comment: I want to get proximity users in indoor places. It doesn't matter if they're at 5m, 50m or over. I was just looking for it. Do you know if it has any limitations, @kd02 ? I mean, can the device receive and transmit at the same moment? Can it broadcast it's signal also in background mode?

Comment: It doesn't sound like iBeacons will help for your use case, they normally have a max range of 40-50m and they only transmit their signal not receive.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is "Apple Indoor Navigation" / "Apple Maps Connect": https://developer.apple.com/maps/

Problem is that this requires your venue to have a million visitors per year or so. If your venue does not fulfill that requirement you should look into some external Indoor Positioning Services. There's a few open-source DIY ones (https://www.internalpositioning.com/) or companies providing full service to you (https://indoo.rs/)

Disclaimer: I do work for indoo.rs.